# Create sleepsort with pthreads in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, sleep

I have just started working with multi-threading in C and I was given a task to create simple sleepsort algorithm. However when I try to run this, nothing is printing. I have no idea what am I doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
void* sleepSort(void* arr) {
    int x = *(int *) arr;
    sleep(x);
    printf("%d ", x);
    return NULL;
}

#define ARR_SIZE 10
#define MAX_ELEMENT 30    
int main(void) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int arr[ARR_SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++)
        arr[i] = rand() % MAX_ELEMENT;
    
    pthread_t threads[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++)
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, sleepSort, &arr[i]);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try putting a `fflush(stdout);` after the printfs.

Comment: Also, maybe output some newlines?

Comment: And maybe `pthread_join(...)` each of the threads instead of calling `getchar()`? That way, there's no guessing how long you should wait before typing the character. Just start the program, and sit back and wait for the output.